# Azure Mobile App testing with Postman returned Error (/table/Student)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-mobile-services

I current trying Azure Mobile App and followed this blog:
https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/11/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-19-asp-net-table-controllers/
However I cannot get data when I run `.../tables/Student` from POSTMAN
I did remain the default TodoItem table unchanged.
 How should I fix this, and what did I done wrong? Please let me know if anymore details needed. Thanks

Models / **elliotAndroidQuickStartContext.cs**

```cs
    public class elliotAndroidQuickStartContext : DbContext
    {
        private const string connectionStringName = "Name=MS_TableConnectionString";

        public elliotAndroidQuickStartContext() : base(connectionStringName)
        {
        } 

        public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("mobile");
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
                new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<TableColumnAttribute, string>(
                    "ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));
        }

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

DataObjects / **Student.cs**

```cs
    //[Table("Student", Schema = "mobile")]
    public class Student : EntityData
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public bool Complete { get; set; }

        // When asked for the string representation, return the JSON
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
    }
```

Controllers / **StudentController.cs**

```cs
    public class StudentController : TableController<Student>
    {
        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);
            elliotAndroidQuickStartContext context = new elliotAndroidQuickStartContext();
            DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<Student>(context, Request);
        }

        // GET tables/Student
        public IQueryable<Student> GetAllStudent()
        {
            return Query(); 
        }

        // GET tables/Student/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public SingleResult<Student> GetStudent(string id)
        {
            return Lookup(id);
        }

        // PATCH tables/Student/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public Task<Student> PatchStudent(string id, Delta<Student> patch)
        {
             return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
        }

        // POST tables/Student
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostStudent(Student item)
        {
            Student current = await InsertAsync(item);
            return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
        }

        // DELETE tables/Student/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public Task DeleteStudent(string id)
        {
             return DeleteAsync(id);
        }
    }
```

App_Start / **Startup.MobileApp.cs**

```cs
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public static void ConfigureMobileApp(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

           config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();

            new MobileAppConfiguration()
                .AddTables(
                    new MobileAppTableConfiguration()
                        .MapTableControllers()
                        .AddEntityFramework())
                .MapApiControllers()
                .ApplyTo(config);

            Database.SetInitializer<elliotAndroidQuickStartContext>(null);

            app.UseWebApi(config);

            MobileAppSettingsDictionary settings = config.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.HostName))
            {
                // This middleware is intended to be used locally for debugging. By default, HostName will
                // only have a value when running in an App Service application.
                app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
                    ValidAudiences = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"] },
                    ValidIssuers = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"] },
                    TokenHandler = config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

http://localhost:59996/tables/Student

```js
{
  "message": "An error has occurred.",
  "exceptionMessage": "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.",
  "exceptionType": "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException",
  "stackTrace": "   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)\r\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.LimitResults(IQueryable queryable, Int32 limit, Boolean& resultsLimited)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(IQueryable query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.ActionFilterAttributeTracer.<>c__DisplayClass4.<<OnActionExecutedAsyncCore>b__1>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__24.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.<ExecuteAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
  "innerException": {
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "The underlying provider failed on Open.",
    "exceptionType": "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException",
    "stackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.TruncatedCollection`1..ctor(IQueryable`1 source, Int32 pageSize)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.LimitResults[T](IQueryable`1 queryable, Int32 limit, Boolean& resultsLimited)",
    "innerException": {
      "message": "An error has occurred.",
      "exceptionMessage": "Cannot attach the file 'D:\\VisualStudio_Project_Location\\elliotAndroidQuickStart_Runtime\\elliotAndroidQuickStartService\\App_Data\\aspnet-elliotAndroidQuickStartService-20160620055432.mdf' as database 'aspnet-elliotAndroidQuickStartService-20160620055432'.",
      "exceptionType": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",
      "stackTrace": "   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__2()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you did not do an Entity Framework Code First Migration when adding the second model.  The database only gets updated when you do a migration.  See http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/migration-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Even I wrote the SQL script which you did in the blog, I still have to do EF Migration? @Adrian Hall